# Deserialization fails if string contains %, []

Tags: json.net

A `JsonSerializationException` is raised when I use JSON.Net to deserialize objects where one of the string values contains a `%` sign (in one case) or square brackets `[]` (in another case).

I am deserializing calendar event reminders downloaded from my Windows Live calendar using their API. Here are the name elements excerpted from the larger JSON event structures (3 different events) that are causing the deserialization exceptions:

- "name": "PCC 5% discount"
- "name": "Paid Holiday [Christmas Eve]"
- "name": "Paid Holiday [Christmas Day]"

The responses look valid and if I paste the JSON received into JSONLint or similar, it validates.

Is there any way to fix or work around these exceptions without discarding the offending objects, or having to preprocess the raw JSON to strip out certain characters?

Comment: If a JSON parser cannot handle % and `[]` in quoted strings, it's not implementing the JSON spec correctly.  But I suspect that your strings are being garbled in transmission, not by the JSON parser.  If the offending characters are not in quoted strings then the JSON text is improperly formed.

Comment: Suggestion:  Post a shortened example of your problem JSON text.

Comment: @Hot Licks, thanks for taking a look. I am using JSON.Net to deserialize calendar event reminders downloaded from my Windows Live calendar using their API. Here are the `name` elements excerpted from the larger JSON event structures that are causing the deserialization exceptions:
  "name": "PCC 5% discount",
  "name": "Paid Holiday [Christmas Eve]",
  "name": "Paid Holiday [Christmas Day]",

Comment: A proper JSON parser should not have trouble with that (assuming the whole mess is bracketed by `{}` characters appropriately).  Are you SURE that's what's being RECEIVED, though, and not simply that that's what's being transmitted?  Those characters are easily garbled in transmission.

Comment: Oops!  I take that back -- that's NOT valid JSON!!!  You've got three successive object elements named "name".  Totally bogus!  (Or did you cut/paste 3 separate elements?  If so, please provide more context -- edit into your original question.)